# Auto Sizing Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I've been looking at this theme http://clapat.ro/berger/ and the way it does it's grid in the middle of it. I've been snooping through the javascript files and it looks like it's auto sizing the '.item' class based on the width.

I'm trying to replicate this sort of sizing but with my novice understanding of jQuery I can't decipher his code easily or understand the way he's sizing his grid elements automatically.

I've made a little JS Fiddle for myself http://jsfiddle.net/7L9aey1c/

```
function MasonryPortfolio() {   

    if( $('#portfolio-wrap').length > 0 ){  

        var $container = $('#portfolio');

        $container.isotope({
          itemSelector: '.item',
          gutter:0,
          transitionDuration: "0.5s"
        });

        $(window).on( 'resize', function () {

            var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
            columnNumb = 1;         
            var attr_col = $('#portfolio').attr('data-col');

             if (winWidth >= 1466) {

                $('#portfolio-wrap').css( {width : 1360  + 'px'});
                $('#portfolio-wrap.no-gutter').css( {width : 1280  + 'px'});            
                var portfolioWidth = $('#portfolio-wrap').width();

                if (typeof attr_col !== typeof undefined && attr_col !== false) {
                    columnNumb = $('#portfolio').attr('data-col');
                } else columnNumb = 3;

                postWidth = Math.floor(portfolioWidth / columnNumb)         
                $container.find('.item').each(function () { 
                    $('.item').css( { 
                        width : postWidth - 80 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75 - 80 + 'px',
                        margin : 40 + 'px' 
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item').css( {
                        width : postWidth  + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75  + 'px',
                        margin : 0 + 'px' 
                    });
                    $('.item.wide').css( { 
                        width : postWidth * 2 - 80 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.wide').css( { 
                        width : postWidth * 2 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.item.tall').css( {
                        height : postWidth * 1.5 - 80 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.tall').css( {
                        height : postWidth * 1.5  + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.item.wide-tall').css( {
                        width : postWidth * 2 - 80 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 1.5 - 80 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.wide-tall').css( {
                        width : postWidth * 2 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 1.5  + 'px'  
                    });
                });


            } else if (winWidth > 1024) {

                $('#portfolio-wrap').css( {width : 1000  + 'px'});
                $('#portfolio-wrap.no-gutter').css( {width : 940  + 'px'});         
                var portfolioWidth = $('#portfolio-wrap').width();

                if (typeof attr_col !== typeof undefined && attr_col !== false) {
                    columnNumb = $('#portfolio').attr('data-col');
                } else columnNumb = 3;

                postWidth = Math.floor(portfolioWidth / columnNumb)         
                $container.find('.item').each(function () { 
                    $('.item').css( { 
                        width : postWidth - 60 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75 - 60 + 'px',
                        margin : 30 + 'px' 
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item').css( {
                        width : postWidth  + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75  + 'px',
                        margin : 0 + 'px' 
                    });
                    $('.item.wide').css( { 
                        width : postWidth * 2 - 60 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.wide').css( { 
                        width : postWidth * 2 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.item.tall').css( {
                        height : postWidth * 1.5 - 60 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.tall').css( {
                        height : postWidth * 1.5  + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.item.wide-tall').css( {
                        width : postWidth * 2 - 60 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 1.5 - 60 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.wide-tall').css( {
                        width : postWidth * 2 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 1.5  + 'px'  
                    });
                });


            } else if (winWidth > 767) {

                $('#portfolio-wrap').css( {width : 640  + 'px'});
                $('#portfolio-wrap.no-gutter').css( {width : 600  + 'px'});

                var portfolioWidth = $('#portfolio-wrap').width(),

                columnNumb = 2;
                postWidth = Math.floor(portfolioWidth / columnNumb)         
                $container.find('.item').each(function () { 
                    $('.item').css( { 
                        width : postWidth - 40 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75 - 40 + 'px',
                        margin : 20 + 'px' 
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item').css( {
                        width : postWidth  + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75  + 'px',
                        margin : 0 + 'px' 
                    });
                    $('.item.wide').css( { 
                        width : postWidth * 2 - 40 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.wide').css( { 
                        width : postWidth * 2 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.item.tall').css( {
                        height : postWidth * 1.5 - 40 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.tall').css( {
                        height : postWidth * 1.5  + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.item.wide-tall').css( {
                        width : postWidth * 2 - 40 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 1.5 - 40 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.wide-tall').css( {
                        width : postWidth * 2 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 1.5  + 'px'  
                    });
                });


            }   else if (winWidth > 479) {

                $('#portfolio-wrap').css( {width : 440  + 'px'});
                $('#portfolio-wrap.no-gutter').css( {width : 400  + 'px'});

                var portfolioWidth = $('#portfolio-wrap').width(),

                columnNumb = 1;
                postWidth = Math.floor(portfolioWidth / columnNumb)         
                $container.find('.item').each(function () { 
                    $('.item').css( { 
                        width : postWidth - 40 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75 - 40 + 'px',
                        margin : 20 + 'px' 
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item').css( {
                        width : postWidth  + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75  + 'px',
                        margin : 0 + 'px' 
                    });
                    $('.item.wide').css( { 
                        width : postWidth - 40 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.wide').css( { 
                        width : postWidth + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.item.tall').css( {
                        height : postWidth * 1.5 - 40 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.tall').css( {
                        height : postWidth * 1.5  + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.item.wide-tall').css( {
                        width : postWidth - 40 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75 - 40 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.wide-tall').css( {
                        width : postWidth  + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75  + 'px'  
                    });
                });


            }

            else if (winWidth <= 479) {

                $('#portfolio-wrap').css( {width : 280  + 'px'});
                $('#portfolio-wrap.no-gutter').css( {width : 240  + 'px'});

                var portfolioWidth = $('#portfolio-wrap').width(),

                columnNumb = 1;
                postWidth = Math.floor(portfolioWidth / columnNumb)         
                $container.find('.item').each(function () { 
                    $('.item').css( { 
                        width : postWidth - 40 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75 - 40 + 'px',
                        margin : 20 + 'px' 
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item').css( {
                        width : postWidth  + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75  + 'px',
                        margin : 0 + 'px' 
                    });
                    $('.item.wide').css( { 
                        width : postWidth - 40 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.wide').css( { 
                        width : postWidth + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.item.tall').css( {
                        height : postWidth * 1.5 - 40 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.tall').css( {
                        height : postWidth * 1.5  + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.item.wide-tall').css( {
                        width : postWidth - 40 + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75 - 40 + 'px'  
                    });
                    $('.no-gutter .item.wide-tall').css( {
                        width : postWidth + 'px',
                        height : postWidth * 0.75  + 'px'  
                    });
                });


            }       
            return columnNumb;


        }).resize();
```

The Full Source Code (Portfolio Masonry Section) http://clapat.ro/berger/js/scripts.js

I'm looking for a bit of advice on how to replicate his grid or how to size the elements automatically instead of statically giving each '.item' element a class of 'width2 height2'.

Comment: Is there a reason the default `Masonary` [layout mode](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html) of `Isotope` won't work for you?  It does adjust dynamically based on available space.

Comment: On the codepen for the first example - they're still using the class 'element-item width2' designating the width of the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use bootstrap, secondly [use isotope v2](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and its [element sizing new feauture](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#element-sizing).

In jQuery you'd run:

```
var $container = $('#container').isotope({
 itemSelector: '.item',
 masonry: {
   columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  isFitWidth: true
 }
});
```

Your html woud look like this:

```
<div class=container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="grid-sizer col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
      <div class="item col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="item col-sm-2 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="item col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-8">
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Not just this would center your layout but it will also be responsive. `grid-sizer` will be your `columnWidth` and it would change its width based on [your bootstrap classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) making the whole thing responsive as you'd expect, on top of this the number of elements that you will see on each row will be based on your bootstrap class settings.

**Note:** You need to specify a grid which uses half the width of each .items if you want different sizes. [See this answer for a more complete code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212194/isotope-2-link-to-specific-filter-from-another-page-like-has-history?noredirect=1#comment44828546_28212194)

I hope that helps

Comment: So will this make the element random sizes or make the elements fit the width?

Comment: what do you mean random sizes? you will define the sizes using bootstrap classes, look at the html there, do you know about bootstrap at all?

Comment: I've used bootstrap multiple times. But are you still defining the widths of each element based on the bootstrap classes? e.g. 'item col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-8' will always be bigger than the first element correct?

Comment: .item width will be defined by bootstrap classes which are responsive. The last .item it is bigger than the other .items indeed but isotope will create the grid based on space available. While .grid-sizer will be your column width. Note they are multiples, can you see that the bootstrap classes of each .item are different but they are multiples and .grid-sizer reflects those multiples too? That's what you need to have different sizes. Also remember you need an height or an element with an height such as img for you boxes

Comment: I have provided a full answer here with the full code and lots of things you might need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212194/isotope-2-link-to-specific-filter-from-another-page-like-has-history?noredirect=1#comment44828546_28212194

Comment: Hmm so the sizes of the items will always have to be set and hard coded? I tried whacking a random image in but it seems to not like it. I'll do a new js fiddle and show you.

Comment: How are you dynamically inserting the images? Php?

Comment: Currently using rails

Comment: use a conditional so that you will output different bootstrap classes to your .item if the image is bigger than or less than and if you add .img-responsive to your images they will adapt magically to whatever .item width is

Comment: Yeah was thinking I would have to do some wizardry on the classes! Would isotope still make the elements fit the container?

Comment: if you do as per my answer here or per the answer i linked you too, yes. isotope will filter .item, all the rest is in regards of the sizes not the filtering

Comment: but I really suggest you to look at the other answer I linked you as it is much more complete, read it all and check the layoutMode I use there as i believe you will need that for your case